# Show UIPickerView like a keyboard, without UITextField

Tags: ios, ios6, uikit

I'm looking for a way to present a `UIPickerView` when the user taps on a `UIBarButtonItem`. Imagine a filter for the table view results.

I know I could use a `UITextField` inputView, but this would not be the case -- all I have is a `UIBarButtonItem` and a `UITableView`.

I've seen into using a [UIActionSheet](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker), but it does not look natural, specially when it's animating to show.

Would animating the `UIView` on and off the screen manually the only option?

The app is iOS 6+ and iPhone only, so I don't need to keep compatibility with any other versions/idioms.

Comment: Do not use a `UIActionSheet`. You are not supposed to add your own subviews to an action sheet. So many apps are going to break when Apple changes the UI for an action sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might not be your only option but animating the UIPickerView should be relatively easy for you to do. Add the picker view so it's displayed off the bottom of the screen. When it's time to animate it in:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - datePicker.bounds.size.height, datePicker.bounds.size.width, datePicker.bounds.size.height);
}];
```

And when it's time to hide it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, datePicker.bounds.size.width, datePicker.bounds.size.height);
}];
```

Answer (score 34):

Attach a UIPickerView as the inputView of a 0-sized UITextField that you have added to your view.

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.dataSource = self
picker.delegate = self
        
let dummy = UITextField(frame: .zero)
view.addSubview(dummy)
        
dummy.inputView = picker
dummy.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: For swift3 use CGRect.zero in the  let dummy = UITextField(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 11):

A better option is still to use the `UITextField`. You don't have to actually show it on screen. Just put it in a 0x0 `UIView` so that it is not visible, set it's `inputView` to your `UIPickerView` and call `becomeFirstResponder` on it to show the picker and `resignFirstResponder` to hide it.

It is convenient to have a `UIView` subclass that implements all of that along with `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: @meaning-matters I added a working Swift implementation as a separate answer.

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest way at least for me, and for Swift4 + Autolayout solution, without a `UITextField` is adding a `UIView` as a container of the `UIPickerView` and a `UIToolbar` for the top views/buttons.

Then toggle the inset/offset of that container view with animation if you want, to hide and unhide the picker.

**PROPERTIES**

```
private lazy var view_PickerContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(self.timePicker)
    view.addSubview(self.toolbar_Picker)
    return view
}()

private lazy var timePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.minimumDate = Date()
    picker.datePickerMode = .time
    picker.setDate(Date(), animated: true)
    return picker
}()

private let timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    return formatter
}()

private lazy var toolbar_Picker: UIToolbar = {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
    toolbar.barTintColor = .blueDarkText
    toolbar.tintColor = .white
    self.embedButtons(toolbar)
    return toolbar
}()
```

I use `SnapKit` to layout my views programmatically. You can use the `timePicker`'s bounds.size as reference for your layout.

**IMPLEMENTATION**

In viewDidLoad()

```
    // Setup timepicker and its container.
    self.view.addSubview(self.view_PickerContainer)
    self.view_PickerContainer.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.equalTo(self.timePicker.bounds.size.height + 50.0)
        make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        self.constraint_PickerContainerBottom = make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(-500.0).constraint
    }

    self.timePicker.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.equalTo(self.timePicker.bounds.size.height)
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    // Add toolbar for buttons.
    self.toolbar_Picker.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.equalTo(40.0)
        make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
```

**Embedding top views**

```
private func embedButtons(_ toolbar: UIToolbar) {
    func setupLabelBarButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Set Alarm Time"
        label.textColor = .white
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
    }

    let todayButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Today", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.todayPressed(_:)))

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePressed(_:)))

    let flexButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    toolbar.setItems([todayButton, flexButton, setupLabelBarButtonItem(), flexButton, doneButton], animated: true)
}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow this helps! Is there any additional way to do it with storyboard? I want to separate my view logic(storyboard) with business logic(swift file).

Comment: @SoeunPark Of course. Just setup your picker container/views and then make an outlet of your bottom constraint to your class. Then you give that bottom constraint a negative large value in either Storyboard or in code in `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: It doesn't work well if the ViewController for the picker is inside UITabBarController. In such cases an approach with zero-frame UITextField is better.

Answer (score 7):

I went with **borisgolovnev**'s suggestion of an invisible `UITextField` and came up with the following **Swift 2.3** implementation:

```
import UIKit

class PickerViewPresenter: UITextField {

    // MARK: - Initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    inputView = pickerView
    inputAccessoryView = pickerInputAccessoryView
    }

    // MARK: - Public

    var pickerDelegate: UIPickerViewDelegate? {
        didSet {
            pickerView.delegate = pickerDelegate
        }
    }

    var pickerDataSource: UIPickerViewDataSource? {
        didSet {
            pickerView.dataSource = pickerDataSource
        }
    }

    var selectButtonAction: (() -> Void)?

    var currentlySelectedRow: Int {
        return pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    }

    func selectRowAtIndex(index: Int) {
        pickerView.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }

    func showPicker() {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func hidePicker() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    // MARK: - Views

    private let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    private lazy var pickerInputAccessoryView: UIView = {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 48.0)
        let pickerInputAccessoryView = UIView(frame: frame)

        // Customize the view here

        return pickerInputAccessoryView
    }()

    func selectButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        selectButtonAction?()
    }

}
```

**PickerViewPresenter** can then conveniently be used as such:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(pickerViewPresenter)
    }

    private let dataModel = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    private lazy var pickerViewPresenter: PickerViewPresenter = {
        let pickerViewPresenter = PickerViewPresenter()
        pickerViewPresenter.pickerDelegate = self
        pickerViewPresenter.pickerDataSource = self
        pickerViewPresenter.selectButtonAction = { [weak self] () -> Void in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            let result = strongSelf.dataModel[pickerViewPresenter.currentlySelectedRow]
            pickerViewPresenter.hidePicker()
            // ...
        }

        return pickerViewPresenter
    }()

    private func presentPickerView {
        let index = 0 // [0..dataModel.count-1]
        pickerViewPresenter.selectRowAtIndex(index)
        pickerViewPresenter.showPicker()
    }

    // MARK: - UIPickerViewDataSource

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dataModel.count
    }

    // MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(dataModel[row]) drunken sailors"
    }

}
```

Hope someone finds this useful =)

Comment: this code doesnt seem to work. I cannot get the showPicker() function to fire. :/

Answer (score 7):

Based on [borisgolovnev's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31368333/5569272) and [CodeMonkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209431/5569272), I have implemented the idea with an invisible `UITextField` in the following way in **Swift 5**.

```
import UIKit

class PickerViewPresenter: UITextField, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    private lazy var doneToolbar: UIToolbar = {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))

        let items = [flexSpace, doneButton]
        toolbar.items = items
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        return toolbar
    }()

    private lazy var pickerView: UIPickerView = {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        return pickerView
    }()

    var items: [Item] = []
    var didSelectItem: ((Item) -> Void)?

    private var selectedItem: Item?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupView() {
        inputView = pickerView
        inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc private func doneButtonTapped() {
        if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
            didSelectItem?(selectedItem)
        }
        resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func showPicker() {
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return items[row].name
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedItem = items[row]
    }
}
```

Usage in your ViewController:

```
private var selectedItem: Item?

private lazy var pickerViewPresenter: PickerViewPresenter = {
    let pickerViewPresenter = PickerViewPresenter()
    pickerViewPresenter.didSelectItem = { [weak self] item in
        self?.selectedItem = item
    }
    return pickerViewPresenter
}()

view.addSubview(pickerViewPresenter)

// e.g. on a button tap
@objc private func buttonTapped() {
    pickerViewPresenter.showPicker()
}
```

**Example:**

I have attached it to a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

[image: Example]