# How can I get a floating wheel date picker with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sheet

I am trying to replicate this form I've found on the Health app:

[image: Date picker from the Health app]

It is a regular sheet. Inside the sheet, there is a `Form`. Then I use an `HStack` with `Text` with the label of the field and another `Text` with the value, separated by a `Spacer`. I watch for the environment's "edit" mode, and when it's true, I transform all Stacks into buttons.

When the user taps the date, on Health, a wheel `DatePicker` shows up. It looks like it's in another sheet, but it's a "bottom sheet", which I could only make work for iOS 16. But that sheet from Health has no radius in its corners. The background is a darker grey, while mine is either white or whatever I define as a `Color` in a `ZStack`. On Health, the only way to close the `DatePicker`'s sheet, is by tapping "Cancel" or "Done" at the top. On my version, it simply goes away by tapping outside.

Am I overthinking this? Is there an easier way to implement this form? I'm really tired of the sheer amount of details. My code is getting huge.

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably looking for a `UIPickerView` set as the `inputView` for a `UITextField` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484506/show-uipickerview-like-a-keyboard-without-uitextfield). I'm not sure if there's a SwiftUI equivalent. You may have to drop down to UIKit for that component.

Comment: I had the same struggle with wheel date picker (it wasn't fully customizable without some hacks that required some hacks to underlying UIKit implementation, which didn't work on iOS 16). So I ended up implementing date picker with `.datePickerStyle(.graphical)`, which can be fully styled with ease.

Comment: @jnpdx This is exactly right! It looks like Health was all made in UIKit, so I have to mix them up. I've made a `UIViewRepresentable` code to tie in the UIKit and it behaves as expected. Mostly. I'll publish the answer soon, unless you want to do it? Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Go for it. Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

As @jnpdx pointed out in a comment to the question, it turns out that the DatePicker on the Health app is written with UIKit and has no equivalent in SwiftUI. So I had to make a bespoke component for that using `UIViewRepresentable`.

This is what I concocted:

```
import SwiftUI

class MuteTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        false
    }

    override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [UITextSelectionRect] {
        []
    }

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        .null
    }
}

struct DatePickerField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date?
    @Binding var isDatePickerVisible: Bool
    var minDate: Date
    var maxDate: Date
    var unset: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MuteTextField {
        let textField = MuteTextField()
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
        datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.wheels
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        textField.textColor = .systemBlue
        textField.textAlignment = .right
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MuteTextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = selectedDate == nil ? unset : selectedDate?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let parent: DatePickerField
        
        init(_ parent: DatePickerField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
            parent.selectedDate = sender.date
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used on SwiftUI. But it turns out it's a text field, which is not what I wanted, so I hid the field, as can be seen on the UIKit component, when I say `textField.isHidden = true`. On SwiftUI I used a ZStack to overlap the field with something else that looks like the field in the Health app. It's not pretty, but can be made into a new component later.

It looks roughly like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if (editMode == .active) {
            HStack {
                Text(fieldLabel)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                Spacer()
                DatePickerField(
                    selectedDate: $selectedDate,
                    isDatePickerVisible: $visibleInput,
                    minDate: minDate,
                    maxDate: maxDate,
                    unset: fieldUnset
                )
            }
        } else {
            HStack {
                Text(fieldLabel)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                Spacer()
                if selectedDate == nil {
                    Text(fieldUnset)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                } else {
                    Text(selectedDate!, formatter: mediumDateFormatter)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's big, but it can be wrapped in another `View`, so it's not too bad.

The Health app also has a red button to clear the value entirely. My date is optional, so it can be `nil`. I will probably add the icon later to set it back to `nil`, but it would be out of scope for this question as my main concern was to show the DatePicker.

I assume a similar approach would be required for the other fields: sex and blood type, which are lists. That component can be expanded or copied to handle that.

Comment: Your strategy of using `parent` like this is dangerous -- the SwiftUI `View` is transient and can be recreated at any time. Better to pass the `Binding` itself (updating it in `updateUIView`)

Comment: @jnpdx, thanks for pointing out. Right. I've made a new code, I'll update the response soon.